# I have to remove some text in data from xpath using strip or split function

Tags: python, xpath, split, strip

actual location

```
"(1)Basking Ridge, NJ"
```

expected location

```
"Basking Ridge, NJ"
```

Comment: This seems to be a Python question, not an XPath question, so it's wrongly tagged.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
>>> location = "(1)Basking Ridge, NJ"
>>> location[3:]
'Basking Ridge, NJ'
```

Comment: location = clean(player.xpath('./td[2]//span/text()'))
        x = location[3:]TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable